# How to hide the address bar of a webpage in android?

Tags: android, javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing address bar from browser (to view on Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068559/removing-address-bar-from-browser-to-view-on-android)

I'm trying to run a web-based application in Android, and I want to hide the webpage address bar while running the application. Is that possible? How do I do it?

Comment: A better more detailed answer/explanation can be found here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068559/removing-address-bar-from-browser-to-view-on-android

Answer (score 16):

Executing this JavaScript on document load will scroll the browser down so that the address bar is off screen:

```
window.scrollTo(0, 1);
```

That's probably as good as you're going to get without writing a native Android app with a `WebView` to display your webapp in.

**Edit:**
Note that this only works for the old default Android browser.  It does not work with Chrome.

Comment: Works in Android 2, but not Android 4.

Comment: Works fine for me in Android 4 (on my Galaxy Nexus).  Are you using the default browser or some other browser?

Comment: it doesn't work on *Google Chrome* and its omnibar (appearing in android 4)

Comment: @Scott Evernden: Chrome officially doesn't support hiding of address bar at this time.

Answer (score 13):

You don't need to use Javascript at all, the Android browser is WebKit based. Adding the following lines

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />
```

in the `<head>` portion of your page will give the desired result.

Comment: Just wanted to add here the comment Stated by Ryan Wheale below: "you cannot rely on the "apple" tags suggested by @Fuzzy. While it may have worked at one time for some Android devices - it is not officially supported by Android OS."

Comment: I have yet to get any of Apple's tags to work correctly in a sane manner with Android.. Honestly, its a guessing game it seems.  Please refrain from stating the obvious things we have already tried, and find ourselves here looking because they never worked in the first place.

Comment: @Fuzzy - The apple meta tags you suggested actually prevent the window-scroll from occurring.

Comment: @Fuzzy Hi. I have used this code in my website. I opened my website from Safari app in iPhone/iPad but the Safari's url and status bar remained visible. :(. All i want is to hide status and url bar when my website is opened in Safari browser app.

Comment: This only applies to web apps installed to home screen (in Safari, tap the middle action button at the bottom and choose "Add to Home Screen").

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add your own `WebView`. Basic help here : http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html

Really, don't forget `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` which will *redirect* all your click in your webview instead of the default browser.