# How to hide url bar in kindle

Tags: javascript, html, kindle, kindle-fire

I would like to know how to hide the URL Bar for a kindle fire from Javascript. I have found some codes but none of them have really worked.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: And what codes did you find where that didn't work (and what do you mean by "none of them have really worked")?

Comment: if the user doesn't interact with the tab bar after a few seconds the url bar disappears. you can't block it permanently afaik (in any mobile browser) as that would stop the user controlling navigation

Comment: Hi David
Thanks for your answser, I have tried the solutions that comes here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759818/how-to-hide-the-address-bar-of-a-webpage-in-android

After sometime the URL Bar doesn't hide automatically, But I guess there most be a way to hide it.

Thanks for your help