# gwt jsni document.documentElement.style.height

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, jsni

I try to call the code from this link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9100406/942113 with gwt jsni.

My method looks like

```
  public static native void hideAddressBar() /*-{
        if (document.documentElement.scrollHeight < $wnd.outerHeight * $wnd.devicePixelRatio) {
            document.documentElement.style.height = ($wnd.outerHeight * $wnd.devicePixelRatio) + 'px';
        }
        setTimeout($wnd.scrollTo(1, 1), 0);
  }-*/;
```

But when I call it, nothing happens.

My question: Isn't it possible to set the value of `document.documentElement.style.height` with gwt jsni?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try referring to it as `$doc` instead of `document`

Ref: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html