# Hide the default browser address bar in android

Tags: android

i am developing one android application, in which , i need to open the url on the default browser.But i don't want to show the browser's address bar.How to solve the problem?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try this [Removing address bar from browser (to view on Android)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068559/removing-address-bar-from-browser-to-view-on-android). If it doesn't, why not use a WebView in your own app? Much simpler that way.

Comment: You can use WebViewClient for the WebView.

Comment: I think you are looking for web page inside your application so just try my answer.