# Full Height site on Android table (Nexus)

Tags: android, jquery, css, web

I'm trying to get the `height` of the Nexus tablet using `$(window).height();` but I'm having troubles as it seems to add the height of the URL bar to the result, which disappears when the user is scrolling.

My page has different sections and each one should look like a full screen page.

The first page looks good until I start scrolling down, as the URL bar disappears and the visible area increases.

I've tried (without success) to hide the URL bar using the techniques explained [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068559/removing-address-bar-from-browser-to-view-on-android), but I can't control it.

Is there any way to deal with this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came with the conclusion that the best option is to avoid the hiding of the URL bar for the Nexus.

This way the calculated size will always fill the screen even on scrolling.

In order to do so I disabled the scrolling on the `html` and `body` elements and used and auto scrolling which scrolls from one to the next section using jQuery.