# Hiding the Address bar in browser for mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

I am developing a cross platform android app in Cordova(HTML 5/Jquery/Javascript). In the app I have a feature where I have a button. It has an hyper link to a website. Now if I click the button the url opens in the mobile browser. 
When the browser is opened one can see the url which is displayed in the address bar.

How can I hide the address bar so that I url is hidden from the user?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing address bar from browser (to view on Android)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068559/removing-address-bar-from-browser-to-view-on-android)

Comment: Alternatively you could use a webview. Gives you much more control over what you show from the website.